# Why results of bitwise left in Java and in C are different?

Tags: java, c

I have a code in c :

```
 unsigned char x = (char)128;
unsigned char y;

y = (x << 1);
  int ye = (int) y;
  printf("%d" , ye);
```

output = 0

I have a code in Java :

```
char x = (char) 128;
char y;
y = (char)(x << 1);
int ke = (char) y;
System.out.println(ke);
```

output = 256

if x = ​​1-127 in c and java are the same, but when 128 and above the results are different,

is there anything I can do for results in java like in C?

Comment: A Java char is a 16-bit value.  Do not use chars to hold byte values.  Java has a `byte` type for that.

Comment: And what is the value of `UCHAR_MAX` on your system? (That's a C value...)  TLDR answer:  Java and C are, surprisingly enough, different languages with different rules.

Answer (score 1):

The 'width' and properties of basic types such as 'char' are undefined in C: It's up to the compiler and architecture.

In java they are all exactly defined.

In java, a `char` is a 16-bit unsigned whole number. Most methods that take chars will interpret this number as a codepoint in unicode (such as `System.out.println()`: `System.out.println((char) 65); prints 'A', not 65.

Evidently, in your C code, `char` is defined as an 8-bit width data type; 128 shifted left by 1, in an 8 bit system, is 0. (it's 256.. which is 100 000 000 - 9 bits; the 9th bit is overflow and is discarded, giving you 0).

Java does not have any data type that represents unsigned 8-bit.

You can use `int` and take care of the overflow rules yourself. You can also use `byte`, and deal with the fact that in java, bytes are signed (methods that operate on them tend to interpret the bits in a signed fashion; bits themselves are what they are and care not for what us humans imagine they might mean. They are neither signed nor unsigned).

Answer (score 0):

The size of `char` is different in C and Java

- **8** bits in C (check `sizeof(char)`)
- **16** bits in Java (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

The shift out bit would disappears, thus

- In C, `x = 128` is `10000000` in binary, `x << 1` results `00000000`, thus `x << 1` is `0`
- In Java, `x = 128` is `0000000010000000` in binary, `x << 1` results `0000000100000000`, thus `x << 1` is `256`